# Unable to install Plotly in Rstudio server

Tags: ubuntu, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am unable to insatll plotly in R studio hosted in a ubuntu server.I am getting the below error message.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/sshuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/sshuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘plotly’
* removing ‘/home/sshuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/plotly’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plotly’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpqMvWWf/downloaded_packages’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to install libcurl4-gnutls-dev, and the problem will be solved.

```
apt-get -y build-dep libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

Comment: How did you find out that this would solve the problem?